# Creation on JSF custom component for credit card

Tags: java, jsf

I need to create one textfield custom components which accepts only credit card number like following format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx and it should accept only number. so how can i do that i know the simple steps of how to create a custom components. and i am using jsf 1.2 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several tutorials:

- [Creating JSF Custom Components](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/07/16/jsfcustom.html) - Contains classic credit card example, JSF 1.0 targeted (old!)
- [Building Custom JSF UI Components](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components) - Simple output component, JSF 1.1 targeted.
- [Guidelines for designing JSF custom components](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/customcomponents.html) - Sun/Oracle's guidelines. JSF 1.x targeted.
- [JSF Component Development](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf4/) - Extended label component, JSF 1.1 targeted.
- [Creating a custom JSF 1.2 component](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/6047/creating-a-custom-jsf-12-component-with-facets-resource-handling-events-and-listeners-valueexpression-and-methodexpression-attributes) - Shuffler component, JSF 1.2 targeted.
- [Creating JSF div component](http://www.it-eye.nl/weblog/2006/04/25/creating-a-jsf-div-component/) - Simple div component, JSF 1.1 targeted.
- [Custom JSF component - Birthday](http://www.codegravity.com/programming/custom-jsf-component-birthday) - Displays today's date and birthdays, JSF 1.1 targeted.
- [Component writing checklist](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2006/12/jsf-component-writing-check-list/) - Overview of differences in JSF 1.0/1.1 and 1.2.

Take your pick. The first and the last ones seems very useful for your particular purpose. I however agree that a simple `Validator` is more than sufficient for this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to write a custom Validator.

- Create a new class that implements the javax.faces.validator.Validator interface and throws appropriate javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException when the input fails validation.
- Register your validator in the faces-config.xml file (under WEB-INF)
- Add an input text (h:inputText) tag to your page and specify the validator using the f:validator tag.

Your custom validator will automatically be invoked with the normal JSF lifecycle when the form is posted.

Comment: but i need to create a custom component that's requirement

Comment: Are you using Facelets? Or just plain ole JSF?

Comment: You probably meant "plain old JSP" there :)